# Webpage not reachable for some people

Tags: http, https, server, web-config

From time to time I got complaints that our webpage is not reachable for some customers. Initially I thought that's their ISP or browsers fault, but last week a colleague was on a business trip abroad and there also couldn't reach it (using his normal laptop where it always worked).

Just as a reference, it's http://schillermedilog.com and https://schillermedilog.com

And now a customer from Germany who can't reach from landline but via his mobile phone. The customer can ping the page, but can't open it in a browser.
For testing I have now set up a new (LinuxMint 19) server with apache and a LetsEncrypt certificate on it. The customer could reach the page on port 80, but not the https version.

I tested with

- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
- https://www.uptrends.de/tools/uptime

but nothing suspicious was reported.

My questions:

- Any hints what the problem might be?
- I can't reproduce the problem on my machine. Are there web-services that can help me reproduce the problem, so I don't have to bother the customer?

Thanks!